# Solr Sort Performance issues

Tags: lucene, solr

I am trying to specify sort on a String field in my query but seeing memory issues since the index has around 50M docs.

Why is that Solr actually sorts the field values for all the documents in the index and NOT just the hits returned from the query. Is there an alternative to these performance problems.

Comment: Can you please show your request?

Comment: Here it is... q=-uid:XXX+%2B(fid:XXX)&sort=firstName%20asc 


SolrQuery result = new SolrQuery(); result.setFields("uid,score,firstName"); . . . . . . result.setQuery(query.toString()); result.setSortField("firstName", ORDER.asc);

Comment: How many documents are in your index and how many are satisfied by the query?

Answer (score 1):

For your query, it may be faster to use filter queries.

```
q=*:*&fq=-uid:XXX&fq=%2B(fid:XXX)&sort=firstName%20asc
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters

Comment: you mean use rangeQueries as fq?

Comment: No, I find that filter queries tend to work faster because they limit the result set that can be returned, which makes the sorting easier. Since your query is simple, I would try it out.

Comment: wouldn't it still load the fields values for all the documents in the index?